# What is Repository in Magento2 and Why use?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

What is Repository in Magento2? Why use this. I want to know more detail about Repository.

Answer (score 0):

Repositories are part of the Service Contracts (they are implementations of interfaces in Api), this means they are meant as public interface to other modules.

In general, the purpose of a repository is to hide the storage related logic.A client of a repository should not care whether the returned entity is held in memory in an array, is retrieved from a MySQL database, fetched from a remote API or from a file.

Repositories generaly have methods like `findById(), findByName(), put()` or remove().but in Magento we call it as  `getbyId(), save()` and `delete()` etc.

Repositories do not come with methods to create a new entity, so in that case you will need a factory. But use the factory for the interface, such as

```
Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory
```

it will create the right implementation based on DI configuration.

Then use the `repository->save()` method to save it.

You can use [this](http://vinaikopp.com/2017/02/18/magento2_repositories_interfaces_and_webapi/) link for more information.